# Error of RMUniversalAlert- UIAlertView+Blocks/UIAlertView+Blocks.h not found

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, cocoapods

My iOS app is using Swift 2.0, RMUniversalAlert version 0.7 and UIAlertView+Blocks version 0.9

When I build it in Xcode 7, error occurs:

> 'UIAlertView+Blocks/UIAlertView+Blocks.h' file not found`
>   It occurs in Pods/Pods/RMUniversalAlert/RMUniversalAlert.m

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This you need to update your pods.

Do a - pod update